# Android: content from diff fragments are not updating

Tags: android, widget, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer and 2 fragments, in each one I have just 1 button.

When I select the first fragment, correct button loads, then I select second fragment, correct button loads. However, if I select back to the previous fragment, the button from the previous fragment remains in the screen.

Would you know why? Thank you so much!

Here are is my fragment selector:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            AssetView assetView = new AssetView();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.assetView_relative_layout,
                    assetView,
                    assetView.getTag()
            ).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            AccountView accountView = new AccountView();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.accountView_relative_layout,
                    accountView,
                    accountView.getTag()
            ).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Here is my fragment 1 xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="it.bitrack.fabio.bitrack.AssetView"
    android:id="@+id/assetView_relative_layout">

    <Button
        android:text="Asset View"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my fragment 2 xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="it.bitrack.fabio.bitrack.AccountView"
    android:id="@+id/accountView_relative_layout">

    <Button
        android:text="Account View"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace fragments in the same container.

**In activity layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"/>
```

**In activity code**

```
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        AssetView assetView = new AssetView();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.container,
                assetView,
                assetView.getTag()
        ).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        AccountView accountView = new AccountView();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.container,
                accountView,
                accountView.getTag()
        ).commit();

    }
```